# Implement search in django

Tags: python, django, search

I have this html search form and I want to link it to my search view to make it work.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" action = "/search/">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the views.

```
def searchResults(request, drname):
    # drname = request.GET.get('drname')
    doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(name__contains=drname)
    clinic = Doctor.objects.filter(clinic__name__contains=drname)
    d = getVariables(request)
    d['doctors'] = doctors
    d['doctors_by_clinic'] = doctors
    return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/(?P<drname>\w+)/$', views.searchResults, name='searchResults'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Html. `<form>` must have `action` attribute, not `<input>`. Also, send search string as get parameter, don't include it in url (add `name` attribute to `<input>`):

   ```
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="/search/">
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="drname">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   </form>
   ```
2. urls.py. Drop this part `(?P<drname>\w+)/`:

   ```
   url(r'^search/$', views.searchResults, name='searchResults'),
   ```
3. views.py. Get search string from `GET` parameter:

   ```
   def searchResults(request):
       drname = request.GET.get('drname')
       doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(name__contains=drname)
       clinic = Doctor.objects.filter(clinic__name__contains=drname)
       d = getVariables(request)
       d['doctors'] = doctors
       d['doctors_by_clinic'] = doctors
       return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborate answer. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

`action` goes in the `form` element, not the input.